# Extbase query to compare two fields in same table

Tags: typo3, extbase

Is it possible to compare two database fields in the query api? For example I want compare the fields tstamp and crdate like:

```
SELECT * FROM tt_content WHERE tstamp > crdate;
```

In the query api I could not found a solution. To get all records and compare the fields in a loop is not a performed way, because this could be over 2 million records (in my real case).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I can think of (and that the query builder supports) is to directly supply the statement. It'll look like this:

```
$query = $contentElementRepository->createQuery();
$query->statement('SELECT * FROM tt_content WHERE tstamp > crdate');
$matchingContentElements = $query->execute();
```

This probably breaks the database abstraction layer, so use it with caution. `statement()` has a second parameter where you can put parameters, in case you need some user input in the query.

Maybe there is another way to do this which I don't know, I'd be really interested in it myself.